# How do I return a value from a console application to a service in .NET?

Tags: .net, windows-services, console-application

I have a .NET service.

I have a .NET console application.

I want something along the lines of the service calling `Process.Start("consoleapp.exe")` and getting some information returned back from the app, ideally just returning a number.

How do I do this?

**Edit:**

I figure it must be: `Process.Start("myapp.exe").ExitCode` - but how do I set the exit code in the console app?

Comment: To set your console application exit code, use Environment.ExitCode;
btw, why cant you add a reference to your Console code in your service application? You could run you Console code without rely on Process class

Comment: @Rubens - trust me I just can't!

Comment: @Rubens: There are scenarios where you need process isolation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Process p = Process.Start("app.exe");
p.WaitForExit();
int number = p.ExitCode;
```

And in app.exe you set Enviroment.ExitCode...

Comment: Ahhh crucial things there being WaitForExit() and Environment.ExitCode! I shall try this now, thanks..

Answer (score 3):

you can make use of an Exit Code by changing your Main method from

```
public void Main(string[] args){return;}
```

to

```
public int Main(string[] args){return 0;}
```

Not an elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: It is to a point.  I guess it's because I'm not a huge fan of relying on arbitrary numbers of an exit code to mean something of use.  Then again I rely on HTTP status codes all the time...

Answer (score 1):

An arbitrary number can be returned via standard [ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx) mechanism. You'd just have to `Start()` a process, then `WaitForExit()`, and then get the value of `ExitCode`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exit code, which can be returned from the Main function or set via Environment.ExitCode.

Another option would be to have your ConsoleApp write to the standard output stream, and redirect the output to your main application.

The advantage of the second option is that you could return more data than a single integer, if later you find this necessary.  The disadvantage is that it's a bit more work to setup.

This [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ProcessStartDemo.aspx) walks through redirecting the standard output streams of a spawned process.

Answer (score 0):

The console app can set its exit code.

The console app can set its exit code by either:

1. Call `System.Environment.Exit(exitcode)`, or
2. Let the `main` function return an int.

The `ExitCode` property (of the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class) lets the service process examine the console app's exit code.